# using multiple left outer joins pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have three tables I am trying to pull data from with the following query:

```
select tats.machine_interval_id as machine_interval_id,
       tats.interval_type as interval_type, 
       tats.interval_category as interval_category,
       ops.opstatemnemonic as operational_state, 
       nptc.categorytype as idle_category,
       tats.interval_duration as interval_duration
from temp_agg_time_summary tats
left outer join operationalstates ops on ops.opstateid=tats.operationalstatenumeric
left outer join nptcategories nptc on nptc.categoryid=tats.categorytypenumeric
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever there is a value that is not null from the `nptcategories` table, it double the record which in turns throws off any calculations I have later in my packages. I believe the problem has to do with having more than one left outer join in the query. My question may see fairly simple, but I'm new to PL/SQL so bear with me.

What I want to know is how can I use multiple left outer joins in a query with out having this problem occur?  What would be a better way to structure this query?

**Update**

Okay so I found the offending line of code it is below:

```
left outer join nptcategories nptc on nptc.categoryid=tats.categorytypenumeric
```

Also when using distinct, it removes all of the duplicate records, but will using this cause any problems I am unaware of?  Should I focus more on figuring out why the join above does not work properly, or is the distinct good enough?

Comment: Having multiple outer joins should not affect the number of rows in the result set. Having extra rows returned is a result of an incorrect join (the `ON` statement, missing some condition), or not having the correct predicates in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Wolf Using distinct gets rid of the duplicate records. But would that be considered a proper fix? Or should i look more into why duplicate records are created in the first place?

Comment: So, are there multiple `categorytypes` for the same `categoryid`?  Because that's the only way that I can see `DISTINCT` fixing your issue... if there's ever multiple `categorytypes` returned for the same "`tats`" record, those results will still be duplicated...

Comment: No, there is only one categorytype returned for each record.

Comment: @James213 Using `DISTINCT` may satisfy the query, but you incur overhead in fetching extra rows and then filtering them out to get unique records. I would keep digging into why you are returning multiple rows when joining to nptcategories. Try seeing if you have extra category records: `select categorytypenumeric, count(*) from nptcategories group by categorytypenumeric having count(*) > 1`.

Comment: @Wolf Good suggestion, that select pointed me in the right direction and now it's fixed. Problem had to do with the table, and not the join after all. Thanks!

Comment: @James213 do post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after taking Wolf's suggestion, i went in and ran the following line of code

```
    select categorytype, count(*) 
from nptcategories 
group by categorytype 
having count(*) > 1;
```

After running this, i found that somehow there were duplicates of records in this table so, this was fixed by removing the duplicates and setting the table to have unique ids. This was done by using the following script on the DB:

```
alter table nptcategories add constraint nptcatidunq unique(categoryid)
```